# How to insert a lot of data into database

Tags: c#, ms-access, bigdata, database

I have a programm in *C#* which downloads data from 4 sources (2 excel sheets,oracle and access database) and calculate them against each other. In the result I have some big results, I keep the results in List. Amount of rows in the result equals approximately 120.000. One row is about 10MB. The result inserts into access database.

How do I insert this list into my databse? Can someone give me an example?

Now I insert rows into table one by one. It costs me about 3 hours to do that.

Comment: Is that SQL Server ?

Comment: Holy cow! 120.000 rows of 10 MB each?! What are you doing in that DB?

Comment: Dragging 1.2 GB over the network and inserting to a database taking 3 hours. That' fair.

Comment: Access database. Row contains of 60 columns, it is financial report.

Comment: How does 60 financial columns take 10 Mb space??? And since it is beyond limits of 32 bits access, is that 64 bits? I would surely first think of moving on to a real database.

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n 60 columns of numbers only ? That should not be 100K and not 10 MB !

Comment: Some of rows are text type.

Comment: It is interesting to see that 10 Mb * 120,000 rows fit on a list without giving out of memory exception. Should be a monster super computer.

Comment: Every column is varchar(max) :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, are you sure 10 Mb * 120000 rows list would fit into your computer's memory when it mean 1.2 Tb and not 1.2 Gb.

Comment: It is not a duplicate IMHO. I am not even sure the OP is right on what he is saying. 1.2 Tb and access doesn't really sound realistic together.

Comment: I am sorry I did a mistake, when I said, that the row is about 10 MByte. The result database equals 1638906 kbyte. The amount of the rows equals 120000. The row is about 13 Kbytes.

Answer (score 2):

Use some kind of bulk insert. If your use entity framework to work with your db's something like this is what you need. Max out the timeout as well.

```
 using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)))
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx.BulkInsert(productsToSync, new BulkInsertOptions()
                    {
                        TimeOut = 10 * 60 * 1000
                    });
                    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SystemLogManager.AddDataSyncErrorLog(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does this require https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/?  You may want to include that in your answer.